# Restless connection to the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an ASP.net web application hosted in IIS. This application use SQL Server.

I removed connection string in `web.config`. But when I start the application, it is still connected to it.
The connection string was nowhere explicitly stated.

how does it work?

Comment: could you show your web.config, app.config, and the constructor of the DbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the machine.config located in *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config* have the following connection string configured.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

By leaving the `<connectionStrings>` section of your web.config empty you are not removing the default connectionstring. To ensure that you have no configured connection string you should use a `<clear />` element in your web.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
</connectionStrings>
```